# Set up automatic synchronisation in rabbit cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

Hi I'm trying to follow the [RabbitMQ HA guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) and implement mirrored queue cluster with automatic synchronization. However when I try to run the following command which should set the policies as per guide it fails:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_policy -p my_vhost HA '^(?!amq.).*' '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}' 
Setting policy "HA" for pattern "^(?!amq.).*" to "{\"ha-mode\":\"all\", \"ha-sync-mode\":\"automatic\"}" ...
Error: Validation failed

[{<<"ha-sync-mode">>,<<"automatic">>}] are not recognised policy settings
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
The version of the rabbit is 3.0, however I have tested this on 3.1 too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've set a similar policy in rabbitmq 3.1.1:

```
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "." '{"ha-mode":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

And I got the response:

```
Setting policy "ha-all" for pattern "." to "{\"ha-mode\":\"all\", \"ha-sync-mode\":\"automatic\"}" ...

...done.
```

Did you ever find a resolution for this?

Looks like you took this to another thread:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/22867

Where the general consensus is that ha-sync-mode is new in 3.1.